# Windows form application to connect Oracle DB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oracle11g

How can my .net based windows application connect to Oracle DB.

I have a working code which is using ODBC and i am referring system.data.ODBC in my code.

This is working fine on dev server , as I have created User DSN and Oracle DB is on same server as Windows Form.

When I move this application to actual end users machine (Same network), they receive an error which states

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

My question is, how can I distribute this working exe application to all the users? Do they need to install Oracle client and configure DSN.

If not system.data.ODBC, which reference can be used to connect to Oracle through .Net so that application can be distributed.

Comment: Have a look at `Odp.Net` http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. But users wont have these components on their machine. We have to ask all the users to install this. Can I just reference these dlls and distribute it? why installation file is so large. Do we need to do this installation on production DB as well, so that application can connect it?

Comment: You can install `Odp.Net` while installing *Oracle Client* (all you have to do is to set a corresponding check box or choose *install all* option), however, you can distribute `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` only. You can even embed this dll as resource of your program.

Answer (score 1):

On the user machine you need to install the driver and set up the same ODBC data source like on your dev server. (same name)